# Android Studio does not install build apk files properly

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I encounter weird issue when developing Android application with Android Studio. It seems that AndroidStudio does not correctly resolve created apk file and trying to use old one.
Build.gradle

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: did you try to clean the project once ??

Comment: Remove the build folder of ur project and build folder of ur module and try to create package

Answer (score -1):

Try these steps

1. Clean Project
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart
3. Rebuild Project